# Double space that I don't know where it came from

Tags: c, reverse

I'm starting to learn C and I'm writing some simple code. In this case I have to write a code that reverse a sentence. I wrote some code and it actually work but at the beginning of the reversed sentence there are two spaces instead of one and I don't know why.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

int i = 0, n = 0;
char a[100] = {0}, b[100] = {0}, c, term;

printf("Write a sentence: ");

while ((c = getchar()) != '\n'){
    switch (c){
        case '.': case '!': case '?':
            term = c;
            break;
        default:
            a[i] = c;
            i++;
            break;
    }
}

for (; i >= 0; i--){
    if (a[i] == ' '){
        for (n--; n >= 0; n--){
            putchar(b[n]);
        }
        printf(" ");
        n = 0;
    }
    else if (i == 0){
        b[n] = a[i];
        for (; n >= 0; n--){
            putchar(b[n]);
        }
    }
    else{
       b[n] = a[i];
       n++;
    }
}

putchar(term);

return 0;

}
```

Can somebody have the patience to help me?

Thank you! :)

Comment: Find out where the blanks are coming from. E.g. by printing "# #" instead of " ". And doing `if (a[i] == ' '){a[i]='@'; ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert a `a[i]='#';` right after the `term = c;`.
You will see that the mysterious blank is actually the content of the array `a`, which could contain the terminating symbol.

This in your code otherwise not intentionally set content gets output, because your loop ends up with `i` referencing this array entry. Here `i++;`, where you sensibly always increment `i` to refer to the next empty array entry.

You then, in your for loop, however start processing that last entry, which never got written to.

To fix that, you could e.g. simply insert a `i--` between while-loop and for-loop.

Session:

```
Write a sentence: I want to try.
try to want I.
```